# Determine an optional parameter which is set same as default value or it has default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I wonder if there is a way update a column (which is not null) as 'NULL'  with optional parameter in this stored procedure.

For example;

testid  test    test2

1         4       3

Update just test column as null

testid  test    test2

1        NULL     3

Edit--
This is a common structure for partial update of a table. But its not possible to set a column(which has a different value than default value of optional parameter) as (default value of optional parameter). If you have other suggestions rather than this for partial updating of a table please share.

Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Pay].[UpdTest] (
    @testid int,
    @test int =null,
    @test2 int =null
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        [Pay].[Test]
    SET 
        test =COALESCE(@test,test)
        test2 =COALESCE(@test2,test2)
    WHERE 
        testid =@testid
END
```

Comment: what is your ask:is it determining or updating ?

Comment: If its possible without determining yes just updating.

Comment: COALESCE returns the first non-null value, and returns NULL if all are NULL. This means that, with the given code, unless the test column is already NULL, the null default for @test will be ignored.  If you want a certain column to be updated to NULL, then reviewing the use of COALESCE might be a good first step.

Comment: You cannot distinguish between a parameter that has been defaulted and one that has been explicitly set to the same value as the default. You can set a column value to `NULL` in an `UPDATE`, just assign the value in the `SET` clause. If you want separate control over defaulting and setting a value then you need two parameters, e.g. `set FooColumn = case when @SetFoo = 1 then @NewFoo else FooColumn end`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments first. This is a common structure for partial update of a table. But its not possible to set a column(which has a different value than default value of optional parameter) as (default value of optional parameter). If you have other suggestions rather than this for partial updating of a table please share. Thanks again.

Comment: Using `COALESCE` as you have shown does preclude setting a non-null column to `NULL`. Ever. You can use a "magic number" to either serve as an impossible default or a signal to force a `NULL`, e.g. `set FooColumn = case when @NewFoo = -42 then NULL when @NewFoo is NULL then FooColumn else @NewFoo end`. IMHO it is clearer to use a separate parameter (as in my earlier comment) rather than magic numbers to control this sort of functionality.

Comment: Using 2 different parameters for each parameter is not practical if we consider a table with too many columns. Using a function which detects magic number may be considerable . But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to tell if the default value of the optional parameter was explicitly specified.  A quick and dirty way is to have the command passed on to SQL as literal, and use a wrapper procedure to test the parameters.  Remember that you'd have to hard-code the default value in the wrapper procedure so if it gets changed, you'd have to change the wrapper of course.

Below is an example of how to process an input SQL command in a very simple manner.  From this wrapper, you can return a flag to notify the main procedure what to do.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestWapper
    (@RESULT INT OUTPUT)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
        @SQL AS NVARCHAR(200), 
        @NumberCommas AS INT,
        @LOC1 AS INT, 
        @LOC2 AS INT,
        @Param1Literal AS VARCHAR(50), 
        @Param2Literal AS VARCHAR(50)

--Set the SQL Command
    SET @SQL  = N'EXEC SetColumnNull 5, NULL';

--How many commas can tell us how many parameters MIGHT have been used
    SET @NumberCommas = LEN(@SQL)-LEN(REPLACE(@SQL,',',''));

--Iterate through and see what the parameters are    
    IF @NumberCommas = 0 
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'no optional parameter was specified'
            SET @RESULT = 0 
            RETURN 
        END
    IF @NumberCommas = 1 --the 1st optional parameter might have been specified
        BEGIN
            --let's get the location of the comma first
                SET @LOC1 = CHARINDEX(',',@SQL);
                SET @Param1Literal = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@SQL,@LOC1+1,LEN(@SQL)))
                IF @Param1Literal = 'NULL' 
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'parameter1 : ' + @Param1Literal + ' was used'
                        SET @RESULT = 1;
                    END
                ELSE
                    SET @RESULT = 0;

                RETURN
        END;

    --IF @NumberCommas = 2 -- do similar things

END
```

If you don't have access to the command text, then I don't see any way to compare NULL as the default parameter value to NULL as the specified parameter value.